# How to add description to the UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I to add a description like "California" in [this image](http://hpics.li/3e57d27).

Comment: Link for image is broken please update the image.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 0)
      return @"California";
   return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its your table header. The table view header for sections. You can have section headers by implementing the datasource method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 1):

In your UITableViewDataSource (a delegate of the UITableView),

this method controls the section header titles:

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a section header.The **UITableViewDelegate** Method is:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 UIView * view = [uiview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 90)];
then Create UIView in UILable ,UItextView etc...
}
then
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 50;
}
```